# Почему приложение Qt с libqgit2 падает в режиме Debug?

Tags: c++, qt, git, lib, qmake

Добрый день.

Мне предстоит использовать функционал `libgit2` в приложении, которое будет написано на `Qt`. К сожалению, на данный момент, существует `Qt wrapper` только для версии  `libgit2-0.22.1` - `libQgit2-0.22.1`, так что выбирать не приходится. Для начала, я выкачал версию `libgit2` [отсюда](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/releases/tag/v0.22.1), а `libQgit2` стянул `git`'ом по ссылке на репозиторий указанной [тут](https://cgit.kde.org/libqgit2.git/). Скачал последний `CMake 3.11.0` и с помощью утилиты `CMake gui` настроил проект, указав в качестве исходников `libQgit2` - корневую папку рабочей дирректории репозитория `libQgit2`, в качестве `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` - `Release` (Хотя, как мне потом объяснили, этот параметр игнорируется при дальнейшей сборке в `MSVS2017`).

- `LIBGIT2_FILENAME` - `false`(чекбокс не отмечен);
- `LIBGIT2_INCLUDE_DIR` - `D:/CPP/GIT/libgit2-0.22.1/include`;
- `LIBGIT2_LIBRARIES` - `LIBGIT2_LIBRARIES-NOTFOUND`;
- `LIBGIT2_SRC_DIR` - `D:/CPP/GIT/libgit2-0.22.1`;
- `PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE` - `D:/Programs/vcpkg-master/vcpkg.exe`.

Остальное не трогал, разве что еще не определился `ZLIB_LIBRARY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND`.
Вот вывод `CMake gui` после `Configure - Generate`.

```html
Using libgit2 source from D:/CPP/GIT/libgit2-0.22.1
Checking for module 'libssh2'
invalid command: libssh2
Commands:
  vcpkg search [pat]              Search for packages available to be built
  vcpkg install <pkg>...          Install a package
  vcpkg remove <pkg>...           Uninstall a package
  vcpkg remove --outdated         Uninstall all out-of-date packages
  vcpkg list                      List installed packages
  vcpkg update                    Display list of packages for updating
  vcpkg upgrade                   Rebuild all outdated packages
  vcpkg hash <file> [alg]         Hash a file by specific algorithm, default SHA512
  vcpkg help topics               Display the list of help topics
  vcpkg help <topic>              Display help for a specific topic

  vcpkg integrate install         Make installed packages available user-wide. Requires admin privileges on first use
  vcpkg integrate remove          Remove user-wide integration
  vcpkg integrate project         Generate a referencing nuget package for individual VS project use
  vcpkg integrate powershel
l      Enable PowerShell Tab-Completion

  vcpkg export <pkg>... [opt]...  Exports a package
  vcpkg edit <pkg>                Open up a port for editing (uses %EDITOR%, default 'code')
  vcpkg import <pkg>              Import a pre-built library
  vcpkg create <pkg> <url>
             [archivename]        Create a new package
  vcpkg owns <pat>                Search for files in installed packages
  vcpkg env                       Creates a clean shell environment for development or compiling.
  vcpkg version                   Display version information
  vcpkg contact                   Display contact information to send feedback

Options:
  --triplet <t>                   Specify the target architecture triplet.
                                  (default: %VCPKG_DEFAULT_TRIPLET%, see 'vcpkg help triplet')

  --vcpkg-root <path>             Specify the vcpkg root directory
                                  (default: %VCPKG_ROOT%)

For more help (including examples) see the accompanying R
EADME.md.

  

========== LIBQGIT2 Build Information ==========
Build Version: 0.22.1
Install Prefix: D:/libqgit2

To change any of these options, override them using -D{OPTION_NAME} on the commandline.
To build and install LIBQGIT2, run "make" and "make install"

Configuring done
Generating done
```

При нажатии на кнопку `Open Project` открывается `MSVS2017`, в котором я делаю `Build Solution` два раза, при выбранном `Debug` и `Release`. В итоге получаю 8 файлов, по 4 для каждой версии - `git2.lib`, `git2.dll`, `qgit2.lib`, `qgit2.dll`. Файлы из версии `Debug` я переименовываю в `git2d.lib`, `git2d.dll`, `qgit2d.lib` и `qgit2d.dll` соответственно. Ошибок в момент сборки не происходит. Далее, я создаю новый проект `Qt Widgets Application`, он собирается `qmake`, а следовательно имеет `.pro` файл настроек. В этом файле я из контекстного меню выбираю `Add Library... -> External library`. В папке с проектом, я создаю директорию `lib` и кладу туда все `8` собранных файлов. В окне подключения библиотеки, в `Library file` я указываю файл `D:\CPP\Qt\GitWidgetApp\lib\qgit2.lib`, в `Include path` автоматом прописывается `D:\CPP\Qt\GitWidgetApp` - корневая директория проекта. Убираю галочки `Linux`, `Mac`, выбираю `Linkage:` - `Static`. В группе настроек `Windows` оставляю галочку на `Add "d" suffix for debug version`. Таким образом, мой `.pro` файл выглядит следующим образом:

```html
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = GitWidgetApp
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG (debug, debug|release) {
    CONFIG       += console
}

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h \
        qgit2.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -lqgit2
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -lqgit2d

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/.
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/.

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/lib/qgit2.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/lib/qgit2d.lib
```

В корневую директорию проекта, я кидаю хидер `qgit2.h` из директории `D:\CPP\GIT\libqgit2`(это рабочая папка репозитория) и переименованную в `qgit2` папку `src`, из которой я удаляю все `.cpp` файлы, оставляя только `.h`. В эту директорию `qgit2`, копирую содержимое директории `D:\CPP\GIT\libgit2-0.22.1\include`. После этого, создаю простую форму в `Qt Designer`, с кнопкой. В `mainwindow.cpp` прописываю вот что:

```
int MainWindow::on_btn_go_clicked()
{
    auto repository = new LibQGit2::Repository();
    try{
        repository->open ("D:/GIT/test_Nivelir_1");
    } catch (const LibQGit2::Exception& e){
        qDebug()<< e.message () << " -- ERROR;";
        return 1;
    }
    qDebug() << repository->listReferences () << " -- OK;";
    return 1;
}
```

Пример взял [отсюда](https://github.com/qtpm/libqgit2).
Приложение все подхватывает, запускается, но вот в чем проблема:
Если я собираю приложение в режиме `Debug` и нажимаю на кнопку, то приложение падает, выдавая следующую ошибку:

[image: Ошибка при краше]

при попытке задебажить все это (`F5`), кидает на `496` строку `qlist.h` -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После `n`'ного нажатия `F10`, в консоль дебаггера выводится следующее:

```html
Debugging starts
HEAP[GitWidgetApp.exe]: 
Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00000295A3B20000, 00000295A5B85080 )
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: ...esktop_Qt_5_11_0_MSVC2017_64bit2-Debug\debug\GitWidgetApp.exe
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp
Line: 904

Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)
```

Что самое интересное, так это тот факт, что в режиме `Release` все в порядке...
Хочется узнать, в чем тут проблема. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Один из корней разного поведения в режимах дебага и релиза может крыться в неинициализированных переменных и проистекающем из них неопределенном поведении

Comment: у вас однозначно ошибка линковки дебаг/релиз версий либы. Ошибка скорее всего кроется в сборке либы, мне этот кусок не совсем понятен. Если вы собираете либус помощью msvc, то зайдите и посмотрите в свойствах проекта что установлено для дебага и релиза, вполне вероятно, что потерялся флаг /MTd

Comment: @goldstar_labs хм, в настройках C и CXX стоять /MD и /MDd для релизной и дебаг версий соответственно. Выставить вместо них /MT /MTd?

Comment: @ФилиппБондарев, попробуйте с /MT /MTd

Comment: @goldstar_labs, попробовал, но ничего не изменилось. Чтож, видимо придется использовать Сишную имплементацию. Спасибо.

Comment: @ФилиппБондарев проверьте все же флаги и ваши переименования lib => libd, у меня была такая же проблема и правильная сборка решила проблему

Comment: @goldstar_labs, в смысле я только что пробовал вместо /MD и /MDd ставить /MT и /MTd соответственно. В итоге те же ошибки. А что вы имеете ввиду под проверкой переименованных .lib? Я не имею опыта в таких делах, пока.